# Error ionic publish google play "You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle..."

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, google-play, publish

I will be very grateful if anyone can help me I have an error in my ionic APP project.

I generate the app normally, I sign everything ok, after putting it on google play I get this error:

"You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without 'android:exported' property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher".

I already tried to put the most recent version of gradler, and change the "android:exported" to "true" but even so when I generate the app it changes the "android:exported" in the androidmanifest to "false".

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that some plugin has not beed updated and is adding an intend where `android:exported` is not set. For me this was the cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing plugin and I fixed it by adding it to that plugin (in the node_modules folder) and then creating a patch for it with patch package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package). This way the patch gets applied every time the plugins are installed.

Can you check which intend is causing the issue and if it is coming from a plugin? If you can't find it, please share your androidManifest.xml and I'll take a look. If it is not a plugin than you should probably fix it from within your config.xml or with a custom hook. But it's probably a plugin, so let's look at that first.